# flink batch in scala (no output)

Tags: flink-batch

I am writing a simple program in flink scala which displays the person's names and ids of clients with consumption (csm) exceeding a certain threshold (100). The compilation of the program completes successfully however I am having the following exception and I don't see the output. I am using the IDE IntelliJ.

Any help ..
thank you.

```
class Client(val name: String, val id:String, val csm: Int) {
  var name_ :String = name;
  var id_ : String = id;
  var csm_ : Int = csm;

  override def toString():String =
  {
   return "Name = " + name_.toString()+".." + "Id = " +id_.toString()
  }

}
object BatchJob {

  val thresold = 100;

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    // set up the batch execution environment
    val env = ExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment

    val client_sample : DataSet[Client] = env.fromElements[Client](
      new Client("Ali Ahmed", "Or70110233", 150),
      new Client("Jean David", "Alg90030456", 80),
      new Client("Ann Hathayway", "Msr65120289", 130)
    );

    val client_excess: DataSet[Client] = client_sample.filter(p => p.csm> thresold);

    client_excess.print();


    // execute program
    env.execute("Flink Batch Scala API Skeleton")
  }
}

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/collection/Seq
    at flinkpack.BatchJob.main(BatchJob.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.collection.Seq
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:352)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
    ... 1 more

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to my pb, in fact all we need to do is just to go
project structure -> modules -> dependencies
convert libraries from 'provided' to 'compile' status.